# "Not all code paths return a value" error in BLL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to write a method with a `try` `catch` where, I'm getting data from a web service, and returning the data as a `string[]`.

I'm struggling with returning the values. Would you mind looking at my code?:

```
public static string[] UserDetailsWebService(string username, string password)
{
    string[] array = null;

    using(WebServiceUser.Users use = new WebServiceUser.Users())
    {
        try
        {
            WebServiceUser.UserGridList Grid = use.GetUserDetails(username, password, username);

            array = new string[] { Grid.FirstName, Grid.LastName };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is NullReferenceException || ex is HttpResponseException
                || ex is WebException || ex is System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
            {
               //throws etc... 
            }
            else
            {
               //throws etc... 
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

The problem is, I get this error :

> Not all code paths return a value.

Comment: Your `return` does not get hit if an exception is thrown.  Do you need a `return array` outside of the `try/catch` as well?

Comment: I would also catch specific exceptions that having a catch-em-all `catch(Exception)` block.  That will make your code cleaner.

Comment: Hey guys, The problem isn't the catch(exceptions), i just need to return data that i took from the webservice, which means string[] array, somehow i am doing something wrong there and i can't fill the Array and return it.

Comment: Put the return array outside the using block

Comment: yepp fixed the problems... that was idiotic sorry >_>

Comment: The `return` statement is not inside the `catch` block, only inside the `using` block which is totally acceptable (I can compile this without an error). Can you show the full code?

Comment: I tried your code [here](http://rextester.com/) and it works fine. I only remove 2 exceptions in the if and replace WebServiceUser with MemoryStream

Comment: @stuartd yeah it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that here the function should return an array of `string`.

Moving `return array;` in the end of function block ensures us that something is always returned.

```
public static string[] UserDetailsWebService(string username, string password)
{
    string[] array = null;

    using (WebServiceUser.Users use = new WebServiceUser.Users())
    {
        try
        {
            WebServiceUser.UserGridList Grid = use.GetUserDetails(username, password, username);

            array = new string[] { Grid.FirstName, Grid.LastName };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is NullReferenceException || ex is HttpResponseException
                || ex is WebException || ex is System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
            {
                //throws etc... 
            }
            else
            {
                //throws etc... 
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: How should this solve the problem? The only difference I see is that you moved the `return` outside the `using`

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. A `return` from inside a `using` block is totally acceptable, there is no need to move it outside.

Comment: Suppose there is an error in `try` block(in your code). In this case nothing will return.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi No, if there was an exception before that the `finally` block of `using` would rethrow it. As I commented below the question, I can compile things like that without that error. But OP already said it fixed his problem, so I'm puzzled...

Comment: @RenéVogt, Well you didn't use `finally` block there. If `finally` block is also be used, you must ensure that the method is return an array of `string`.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi the `using` keyword is translated into an `try/finally` block where `finally` disposes the `WebServiceUser.Users`. But that actually is not relevant. If an exception occurs, there is no need for a return. The point is, the `using` is no `if` or something like that. In the code shown by OP, _every non-exceptional_ code path ends in the `return array;` so I still don't see why he got that error. I have tons of equal samples that do compile without errors.